# Combine 2d-array into tuple

Tags: python, point, multidimensional-array

I want to combine two 2d-arrays into one NX2 array, but I don't know what command should I use in python.
For example, `a = [1.2.3] b = [4,5,6]`, and I want to have a new array which have the elements in a as the x-coordinate and b as the y-coordinate, `c = [(1,4)],(2,5),(3,6)]`

Any hint for this in python language?

Answer (score 6):

You're lucky, because Python has a built-in [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function that does exactly what you want.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(a, b)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Note that in Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator, not a list, so you will have to use `list(zip(a, b))` to get a list.

Also note that `zip` truncates the length of the result to the smallest list.

For example:

```
>>> zip([1, 2], [3, 4, 5])
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

You can combat this with [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (or `itertools.zip_longest` in Python 3).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], fillvalue=0))
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 5)]
```

This will use the `fillvalue` to fill in the empty gaps. By default, `fillvalue` is set to `None`.

Comment: Maybe a caveat about equal lengths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function.

```
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [1,2,3,4]
    nodes = [zip(x,y)]
```

Use zip() inside list() to get the list. Or else it will print as,

```
[<zip object at 0x0000024AE84502C0>]
```

Do it i this way instead

```
nodes = list(zip(x,y))
```

It is going to print

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```